What is the lipsum package?
What is this lipsum package I keep on seeing? How can I use it and how is it useful? Does it do anything except add the \lipsum command? The \lipsum command just generates nonsense, so how is it useful?

Welcome to TeX.SE. What makes you think that the output of \lipsum is spam?

It's very long and not in any language, but now I realize that it is the lorem ipsum thing.

“It’s … not in any language” — is Latin not a language in your book?

Mandatory reading: Lorem ipsum.

@mico No, lorem ipsum is broken Latin. Try putting a few sentences into google translate.

Since you mention Google Translate: If one inputs a few Lorem Ipsum sentences and instructs the program to identify the language, it returns "Latin". The fact that Google Translate cannot translate the text to English (or any other language!) is due to the deliberately nonsensical nature of the input text. Nonsensical English is still English, nonsensical German is still German, and nonsensical Latin is still Latin. Your claim that Lorem Ipsum text is "not in any language" is false.

No, you can see that it returns some of the words at it is. I think it takes a real Latin script and jumbles it, adds characters, deletes some of it, etc. and for some of it it is a coincidence that it can be translated.

Suppose I want to test a particular typographic realization of some book. In this case I want to evaluate a style for the headers. I need to look at a spread from some distance in order to see whether the style is effective or needs some change.
The spread should be full of text, but I'm lazy and don't want to type in a lot of paragraphs. I can use lipsum (or its competitor kantlipsum) to get nonsense text for free.
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize\bfseries\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter test title}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section test title}

\lipsum[3-20]

\end{document}


Maybe I might add a section title in the spread in order to see what happens. Just change the body into
\chapter{Chapter test title}

\lipsum[1-6]

\section{Section test title}

\lipsum[7-20]

to get

I can now maybe test a different style for the titles, which can only be done when they're surrounded by text. Or different dimensions for the text width or height. Looking at a complete spread is essential.

I wonder if there are similar texts with equations?

@yarchik Try blindtext

The lipsum package is for producing placeholder text. It is useful for examples, in which you need to show some text to reproduce something, but the text itself doesn't matter. For example if somebody asks about a problem with page headers on the second page of their article, their example document needs to be at least two pages long. That's easy with the lipsum package.
Alternatively you could actually type random text in your code, but this makes it harder to see the code which actually matters.
The basic usage is
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}

For more options and customisation, see the package documentation.

If you'd like a more fun way to generate test documents, have a look at the duckuments package. Instead of just gibberish, it will print a cute story about a little duckling:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}


"Random" in this case means "nonsense," not statistically random nor even pseudo-random.  Mostly it is a convenient way to add text to a MWE.

Replaced random with placeholder

Sometimes a document, especially a test document, needs filler text to achieve some typographical objective. By "filler text", one generally means a collection of lines, or even entire paragraphs, of text meant to take up space while deliberately not possessing any particular meaning. Because the insertion of filler text is deliberate, I would definitely not call the output of \lipsum "spam".
The lipsum package provides a convenient method for generating such filler text. The fact that its output is ostensibly in Latin (though still nonsensical) reinforces its filler-text nature. Other LaTeX packages that can generate filler text are kantlipsum and blindtext.
